# iOS : 64 bit architecture error ignoring file

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit

```
ignoring file UserVoiceSDK-1.2.6/libUserVoice.a, missing required architecture x86_64 in file UserVoiceSDK-1.2.6/libUserVoice.a (3 slices)
```

I am getting this error when trying to convert my App to 64 bit. Is there a around this? I can't seem to find libuserVoice.a that supports 64 bit.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to use 32bit static library in 64bit.

Comment: Either you should remove arm64 bit flag from valid architecture or you should find source code for libUserVoice.a SDK and try to create new library file for 64bit.